# Python array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am confused about doing vectorization using `numpy`.

In particular, I have a matrix of this form:
of type `<type 'list'>`

`[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.02, 0.04, 0.0325, 0.04], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

How do I make it look like the following using numpy?

```
[[  0.0   0.0   0.0     0.0  ]
 [  0.02  0.04  0.0325  0.04 ]
 [  1     2     3       4    ]]
```

Yes, I know I can do it using:

```
np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.02, 0.04, 0.0325, 0.04], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

**But I have a very long matrix, and I can't just type out each  rows like that. How can I handle the case when I have a very long matrix?**

Comment: np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.02, 0.04, 0.0325, 0.04], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

Comment: Hi Erotemic, can you please see my update?

Comment: how do you get the matrix you don't want to type? In what form does it exist now (e.g. I have an array of arrays, a CSV file, a generator function)?

Comment: When I ran `type(A)`, it gave me the following `<type 'list'>`

Comment: and what is np.array(A) ?

Comment: There is no difference between these two arrays. Do you only want to print formated row by row?

Comment: I don't get the question? Do you want to just use a long flat list of numbers and reshape it to the desired 2D form.

Comment: @wrek your question is not clear. You have a very long matrix but you don't want to type it in? Well where is it? Is it in a file? In a list? It must be somewhere. At some point you must have it in memory and call np.array. I guess you could use np.fromiter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you start with a large array, why not split it into arrays of the right size (`n`):

```
splitted = [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(array), n)]
```

and make the matrix from that:

```
np.array(splitted)
```

Comment: You could just use `np.array(A).reshape` to get this form much faster.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a matrix of type list, it is a list that contains lists.  You may think of it as matrix, but to Python it is just a list

```
alist = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.02, 0.04, 0.0325, 0.04], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

arr = np.array(alist)
```

works just the same as

```
arr = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.02, 0.04, 0.0325, 0.04], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

This creates 2d array, with shape (3,4) and dtype float

```
In [212]: arr = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.02, 0.04, 0.0325, 0.04], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [213]: arr
Out[213]: 
array([[ 0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ],
       [ 0.02  ,  0.04  ,  0.0325,  0.04  ],
       [ 1.    ,  2.    ,  3.    ,  4.    ]])
In [214]: print(arr)
[[ 0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.02    0.04    0.0325  0.04  ]
 [ 1.      2.      3.      4.    ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying you have a list of lists stored in Python object `A`, all you need to do is call `np.array(A)` which will return a numpy array using the elements of `A`. Otherwise, you need to specify what form your data is in right now to clarify how you want to load your data.